# Replacement for “Up to”

Tags: synonyms

Could you please suggest some words to replace "Up to"?

> Up to 14% increase in turbine power and 9% increase in turbine
>   efficiency are achieved by optimizing the duct geometry.

Comment: @LeonMeier No, "till" or "until" are not useful here; they refer only to time in English.

Comment: _"**As much as a** 14% increase..."_ is a useful substitution.

Comment: @LeonMeier _At most_ is possible; "till" is not.